# Группировка по дню из даты с помощью JPA Criteria API

Tags: java, jpa, criteria, criteriabuilder

Задача состоит в том, чтобы сгруппировать события по определенному дню, чтобы сделать это, я должен вытащить день из даты и сгруппировать записи по нему. Ранее мы использовали MySql, и этот код работал как следует:

```
public static Specification<AllFile> findByGroup(FileFilter fileFilter) {
return (Specification<AllFile>) (root, query, cb) -> {
    final Collection<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    if (fileFilter.getStart() != null && fileFilter.getEnd() != null) {
        Date date = new Date(fileFilter.getStart().getTime());
        date.setHours(0);
        date.setMinutes(0);
        date.setSeconds(0);
        date.setDate(1);

        predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("created"), date));
        predicates.add(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("created"), fileFilter.getEnd()));
    }
    else if(fileFilter.getStart() != null) {
        Date date = new Date(fileFilter.getStart().getTime());
        date.setHours(0);
        date.setMinutes(0);
        date.setSeconds(0);
        date.setDate(1);

        Date newDate = DateUtils.addMonths(date, 1);

        predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("created"), date));
        predicates.add(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("created"), newDate));
    }

    if (fileFilter.getRoute() != null) {
        predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("route"), fileFilter.getRoute()));
    }

    if (fileFilter.getDevice() != null) {
        predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("device"), fileFilter.getDevice()));
    }

    if (fileFilter.getType() != null) {
        predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("type"), fileFilter.getType()));
    }

    if (fileFilter.getUser() != null) {
        predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("user"), fileFilter.getUser()));
    }

    if (fileFilter.getDeleted() != null) {
        predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("deleted"), fileFilter.getDeleted()));
    }



    query.groupBy(cb.function("day", Date.class, root.get("created")));
    return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
};
```

}

Но после перехода на Postgres такой подход работать перестал. для корректной работы мне нужно отправить нечто вроде этого:

```
select extract(day from allfile0_.created) as dd
from all_file allfile0_ 
where allfile0_.created>='Tue Oct 01 00:00:00 MSK 2019' and 
allfile0_.created<='Fri Nov 01 00:00:00 MSK 2019' 
group by dd
```

Вместо этого:

```
select allfile0_.id as id1_0_, allfile0_.added as added2_0_, 
allfile0_.comment as comment3_0_, 
allfile0_.created as created4_0_, allfile0_.deleted as deleted5_0_, 
allfile0_.device_id as 
device_13_0_, allfile0_.duration as duration6_0_, allfile0_.mark as 
mark7_0_, allfile0_.path as 
path8_0_, allfile0_.recognition as recognit9_0_, allfile0_.route_id as 
route_i14_0_, allfile0_.size 
as size10_0_, allfile0_.type as type11_0_, allfile0_.updated as 
updated12_0_, allfile0_.user_id as 
user_id15_0_ 

from all_file allfile0_ 

where allfile0_.created>='Tue Oct 01 00:00:00 MSK 2019' and allfile0_.created<='Fri Nov 01 00:00:00 MSK 2019' 
group by extract(day from allfile0_.created)
```

Возможно ли получить такой запрос, как мне нужно с помощью Criteria API? Нужен совет по поводу кастомного select, чтобы выбирать именно то что мне нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменил

```
query.groupBy(cb.function("day", Date.class, root.get("created")));
```

на

```
query = cb.createTupleQuery();
        root = query.from(AllFile.class);
        query.select(root.get("created")).
                groupBy(cb.function("day", Integer.class, root.get("created")));
```

после чего код отработал как надо.